# Get flipview ItemsPresenter to show next and previous items

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, flipview, itemspresenter

I have a uwp flipview, and want to get it to show a bit of the next and previous elements. Essentially, this means make each flipviewitem slightly smaller, so that you know that the flipview can be scrolled across. Here's a screenshot of what I currently have:

[image]

The flipview is the part with the circular image of Michael Fassbender. You can swipe to the next one, so I want to show a bit of the next image to the left. I've noticed that the FlipView default style has an ItemsPresenter inside a scrollviewer (we can modify a FlipView default style by right click it in Visual Studio/Edit Style/Edit a Copy ...). If I set the margin of that ItemsPresenter to say -100 on each side, it works at some points, but the behavior is weird, unpredictable, and depends of the window's width. What other solution would there be?

Answer (score 2):

> If I set the margin of that ItemsPresenter to say -100 on each side, it works at some points, but the behavior is weird, unpredictable, and depends of the window's width. What other solution would there be?

You are right about setting the `Margin` of that `ItemsPresenter`, but I think the value of -100 can't solve the problem here, and it should depends on the `FilpView`'s width, not the window's width. Here I have a solution also setting the `Margin` property:

```
<ItemsPresenter Margin="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource marginvct}}" />
```

And my converter is like this:

```
public class MarginConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var width = (double)value;
        double itemmargin = width / 6;
        Thickness margin = new Thickness(itemmargin, 0, itemmargin, 0);
        return margin;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

As you can see from this code, I set the width of each item to 2/3 of the whole `FlipView`'s width and keep the left and right sides have a space with 1/6 of the  `FlipView`'s width, so will the next, current and previous elements be shown together.

And since I bind the value of `Margin` to `Width`, when using `FlipView` now, the `Width` property should be set. You said it depends on the window's size, I guess that you want your `FlipView`'s width equal with the window's width, so for example you can code like this:

```
<FlipView ItemsSource="{x:Bind collection}" Style="{StaticResource FlipViewStyle}" Width="{x:Bind CustomWidth}">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ContactImage}" />
                </Grid.Background>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Ellipse Width="200" Height="200">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ContactImage}" />
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,30,0,0" Text="{Binding ContactName}" FontSize="25" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,15,0,0" Text="{Binding ContactNumber}" FontSize="20" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="0,15,0,0" Text="{Binding ContactAddress}" FontSize="20" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

The code behind for the `CustomWidth` is like this:

```
private double CustomWidth;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    CustomWidth = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
}
```

Here is the rendering image of this demo:
[image]

Comment: It still seems to react strangely to size changes :/ I'm setting the size of the flipview to the window's width on the Page's SizeChanged event. I also get a behavior where the margin isn't always the same width:

Comment: @user2950509, I couldn't reproduce your problem, I didn't find any strange thing here by margin. But if setting the width to flipview in page's SizeChanged event, you will need to implement INotifypropertyChanged here to notify the `FlipView` to change its width, and at first it's also important to give a initial value to the width, otherwise error will occur. And did you check my answer in your last question?

Comment: This is the behavior I get: http://imgur.com/vGEqdAo . As you can see, the items also ocasionnaly disappear.

Comment: And about the width, all I do is set it this way: flipview.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width; on the Page's SizeChanged event :/

Comment: @user2950509, I think it's normal the item will disappear during changing the window's size, cause during this time the margin value will always be recalculated. And I still couldn't reproduce your margin problem druing SizeChanged, how did you set the margin?

Comment: I used the exact converter you gave, and binded the ItemsPresenter Inside the flipview's style using `Margin="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource marginvct}}" />` . I think the margin issue might have to do with the fact that the photo doesn't stretch to the width of the FlipView. It's a fixed sized (175x175).

Comment: @user2950509,  I used images as ImageBrush to fill the fixed size of Ellipse, this problem will not occur. How did you get the circular image? Is the image source already a circular one?

Comment: The circular image is a 175x175 rectangle with a RadiusX and RadiusY set to 88. This is my xaml: http://pastebin.com/3iwUP8nH, And this is the c#: http://pastebin.com/9VJfS6G9 . The FlipViewStyle is the normal one, with the ItemsPresenter switched to this: `<ItemsPresenter Margin="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource marginvct}}"/>`

Comment: @user2950509, I tested your code, I still can't reproduce your strange behavior unless using a VisualStateManager target on the ItemPresenter.Margin in the style or set a static value to margin. Did you use these methods? And we properly discussed too much under this answer.